# Python zip list of tuples

Tags: python

How can I zip a list of tuples in Python?

```
# From
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]

# To
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: assuming you want to retain elements as tuple, try `list(zip(*tuples))`

Comment: reason why I am a bit confused, because in the desired transformation, `tuples` is a misleading name, as you end up with a list of lists above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use zip and list comprehension.

```
>>> tuples = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(*tuples)]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Or,

```
>>> tuples = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
>>> [[*i] for i in zip(*tuples)]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using numpy then

```
import numpy as np
l=[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
[tuple(i) for i in (np.array(l).transpose())]
```